# Openlayer 3 - check if a feature is within bounds of extent

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a list of features and a vector layer and I need to know, whether each feature is within the bounds of the view of the map or not.

I'm using openlayers v3.9.0 and in the corresponding documentation there is a function `containsExtent()` ([link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.extent.html#.containsExtent)) which takes an extent and returns a boolean. Seems to be exactly the function I'm looking for. But an error is thrown saying that containsExtent is not a function.

`Uncaught TypeError: extent.containsExtent is not a function`

code snippet:

```
// someVectorSource is of type ol.source.Vector
// allMyFeatures is an array of features of type ol.Feature

var extent = someVectorSource.getExtent();
_.each(allMyFeatures, function(feature) {
  if (extent.containsExtent(feature.getGeometry().getExtent())) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

What is the problem here?

If the is a better way, to get only those features which are within the extent, in a single call without iterating through the list, would be even better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
ol.extent.containsExtent(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent())
```

If you look closer at the [doc page](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.extent.html#.containsExtent), you'll see that the method is a static one, not part of a `ol.Extent` object.  FYI, there's no actual `ol.Extent` object in ol3.  It's just an array of 4 numbers.  I think `ol.Extent` is just a reference for the compiler.

HTH